# Leaflet get sub-polyline with specific start and end point

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline

I want to get a "sub-Polyline" of a given polyline that is determined by a certain start and end point (in meters).

For example I have a polyline that is 500 meters (build using 30 coordinates (not seperated in same spaces)) and I want to color the line between meter 200 and 300 in a different color. Is it possible using Leaflet functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the LineStringSelect plugin here: https://github.com/w8r/L.Control.LineStringSelect

With the demo (click in 2 different locations on the polyline):

https://w8r.github.io/L.Control.LineStringSelect

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! This looks really good, but it seems limited to user operation and selections .. Do you have a clue how to use the selection with "fixed" values and without user input?

Comment: @David sorry for the late reply. Not directly, but the code will be in there to convert 2 points to a series of points along a given polyline.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are asking "If I have a polyline and a distance value, what is the point along the polyline with the desired length-distance to the line's starting point"?

This algorithm has been covered a multitude of times, e.g.:

- http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html,  http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Substring.html
- http://turfjs.org/docs/#along
- https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim

The algorithm is always the same: divide the polyline/linestring into segments, measure length of each segment, locate the point, apply direct interpolation in the segment that the point is in.

Keep in mind that geometry in a 2D cartesian plane is different than geometry in the surface of a geoid, particularly when it comes to measuring distances. Do a bit of research on [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) and its methods for manipulating geodesic lines.

To your question «Is it possible using Leaflet functions?», the answer is «**no**, Leaflet does not implement this algorithm». The easiest way for you should be to read the source code of the mentioned Leaflet plugins in the answers, or use the `along()` method from the Turf library.